# how to open up an editable dialog to post a tweet

Tags: javascript, android, ios, twitter, titanium

I'm wondering if there is a way when I click on a button to open up a dialog with a predefined message which the user can (i) edit(text field) (ii) cancel out of (button) and (iii) press ok (button) thus tweeting.
I'm using the codebird module and titanium with the following link
https://gist.github.com/Rogichi/5905010
This enabled me to send a tweet but only with a set text and no ability to edit, press ok or cancel. Also it only works on the first time you run the app on the phone, after that, I have to uninstall and re-install before I can send again.
Any help at all would be much appreciated

Comment: @Josiah Hester you seem to be somewhat of a Titanium guru. If you have dealt with this before I'd appreciate any advice you could offer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to create the window with the two buttons and a textarea so the user can compose his own tweet. i managed to do this using the codebird files you mention, all you have to do is edit the setTweet function like this:(everything else stay the same, doing this enables to send as many tweets with out relaunching the app. good luck)

```
function setTweet(){
    var post = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title : 'Send',
        right: 10,
        width: 80,
        height: 30,
        top: 10
    });
    var content = Ti.UI.createTextArea({
      color: '#888',
      font: {fontSize:20, fontWeight:'bold'},
      textAlign: 'left',
      value: 'compose a tweet',
      top: 60,
      width: 280, height : 140
    });
    var floatW = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        borderWidth:8,
        borderColor:'#999',
        height:200,width:300,
        borderRadius:10
    });
    floatW.add(post);
    floatW.add(content);
    floatW.open();
    post.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        var tweet = content.getValue();
        cb.__call(
            "statuses_update",
                {"status": tweet },
                    function (reply) {
                    Ti.API.info("Respuesta al publicar: ");// ...
                    Ti.API.info(reply);// ...
                        ///////////INSPECT OBJECT
                    function inspeccionar(obj){
                        var msg = '';
                        for (var property in obj){
                            if (typeof obj[property] == 'function')
                            {
                                var inicio = obj[property].toString().indexOf('function');
                                var fin = obj[property].toString().indexOf(')')+1;
                                var propertyValue=obj[property].toString().substring(inicio,fin);
                                msg +=(typeof obj[property])+' '+property+' : '+propertyValue+' ;\n';
                            }
                            else if (typeof obj[property] == 'unknown')
                            {
                                msg += 'unknown '+property+' : unknown ;\n';
                            }
                            else
                                {
                                    msg +=(typeof obj[property])+' '+property+' : '+obj[property]+' ;\n';
                                }
                        }
                        return msg;
                        }

                //Ti.API.info(inspeccionar(reply));
                //Ti.API.info(inspeccionar(reply.errors[0]));
                    //Ti.API.info(reply.httpstatus);

                if(reply.httpstatus == 200)
                        floatW.close();
                    else
                        alert(reply.errors);
                }
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: Soo helpful. Thank you very much

Comment: This code worked on its own but when integrating into my app I never got past the loading access token alert. I put extra alerts in all conditions and i found that it was stopping in the if (file.exists() == false){
            return;
        } statement. Any idea why the file wouldn't exist?

Comment: I figured it out. I had two instances of the module in my app so one needed to be var cb= new Codebird and the other had to be different i.e. var cb2 etc. becausee there are a lot of things going on with bearer tokens etc. in both instances

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a [module like this one on the marketplace](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/4015?1938575784) or this code by [Dawson Toth.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72781789/social.js)

You will have to make the actual window to send the tweet and edit the message, this should get you started:

```
// Set up twitter first
var social = require('social');
var twitter = social.create({
    site : 'Twitter',
    consumerKey : '*****',
    consumerSecret : '*****' // <--- and this with your own keys!
 });

// Now create your popup window 
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({layout : 'vertical'});
var tweettext = Ti.UI. createTextField({
  hintText : 'Enter what you want to tweet...',
  borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
  color: '#336699',
  height: 60
});
var send = Ti.UI.createButton({title : 'Send', height : 45});
send.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Send the tweet with the text fields value
    twitter.share({
        message : tweettext.value,
        success : function() {
            alert('Tweeted!');
        },
        error : function(error) {
           alert('You have already shared this school on Twitter.');
        }
    });
});
// Cancel button closes the window
var cancel = Ti.UI.createButton({title : 'Cancel', height : 45});
cancel.addEventListener('click', function(e) { win.close(); });

// Add all controls and open the window as a modal
win.add(tweettext);
win.add(send);
win.add(cancel);
win.open({modal: true});
```

That should give you the idea and enough to get started. Havent tested this, you may have to work with it.

Comment: thanks for this. I've already tried the module you suggested and it opens up the sign in screen but doesn't send a tweet or having any sample of doing so in the app.js file in the example folder. I'm getting a warning in the console: [WARN][System.err(  789)] {"errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", "code": 68}]}
So it seems to be out of date since the new twitter API was released. I'll look into the code by Dawson Hoth. In your code you have var social = require('social');

Comment: Is this another module I have to download from the market place?

Comment: oK, I found the module. The code isn't working, however. It opens up the authorisation screen and goes through the progress bar and then opens a page with a 404 error that it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

you can use the twitter intent urls in a webview

see this StackOverflow question

[Is there a way to launch a Twitter dialog for sending direct messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481701/is-there-a-way-to-launch-a-twitter-dialog-for-sending-direct-messages)